# Handling out of date answers

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

What is the best way to preceed if we notice an answer that is not correct anymore for instance after a protocol update?

The three options I see are:

- Adding a comment to the answer to notify the author: fair to him but assume he is still participating and willing to update the text.
- Editing the answer: I think it requires an approbation by the initial author (who may never come again) and the reward for the new author is small.
- Adding a new answer: it gives more reward to the new author, it may become the accepted answer (helpful for futur readers).

I seems to me that the polite way would be to let a comment and then to add a new answer after some time without response.

Comment: i would like guidance on this as well. For example regarding fees and other things like that

Comment: While a comment first followed by an answer would be polite, i think a new answer is ultimately what is desired. Ideally people would flag the previous answer for moderation and we could edit it to add a note that the answer may be out of date? This way a new reader is made aware that they should read the other answers.